# pandas function to check if there exist non-NA values for the same ids?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, data-preprocessing

Assume I have a dataset that contains around 100 000 rows and 50 columns.
I have information about the sellers and their products. The part of the dataset will look somehow like this:

| seller_id | product_id | seller_is_checked | size | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A100** | **UN76UH** | **1** | **uni size** | **red** |
| B200 | HJHLI90 | 0 | small | blue |
| C300 | UUKB89 | 0 | large | green |
| <...> | <...> | <...> | <...> | <...> |
| **A100** | **BxYJHG** | **NA** | **medium** | **purple** |
| AXYZ215 | HHIOTY | 1 | large | unknown |

In the table you can see that there are at least two `seller_id`s as these seller has several products. However, this time there was a mistake while entering the data and the information whether the `seller_is_checked` got missing.

Is there a function in Python/pandas that will help to look through the data set and substitute the missing value with the actual one from the same data set?

Comment: This is a pandas question, you should also tag it [tag:pandas], and edit the title to specifically say "pandas function" not just "Python function". But once you tag and title it correctly, you'll find hundres or thousands of existing duplicates on that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, which is based on the idea of filling downwards and then upwards the missing values with a valid observation in each group of `seller_id` ([`pandas.DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)):

```
df.seller_is_checked = df.groupby('seller_id')['seller_is_checked'].ffill().bfill()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  seller_id product_id  seller_is_checked      size    color
0      A100     UN76UH                1.0  uni size      red
1      B200    HJHLI90                0.0     small     blue
2      C300     UUKB89                0.0     large    green
3      A100     BxYJHG                1.0    medium   purple
4   AXYZ215     HHIOTY                1.0     large  unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pandas for example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the data into DataFrame which is basically a two dimensional array
df = pd.read_csv("you_csv_file.csv")

# Print if there are null values
print(df.isna().sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating a dictionary for seller_id and then updating the seller_is_checked info. Follow me (assuming you are using pandas):

1 - remove lines where seller_is_checked info is missing and create a new dataset, seller_dict_df with the results

```
seller_dict_df = df.dropna()
```

2 - create the dictionary

```
seller_dict = dict(
    zip(
        seller_dict_df['seller_id'], seller_dict_df['seller_is_checked']
        )
    )
```

3 - update the original table

```
df['seller_is_checked'] = df['seller_is_checked'].replace(seller_dict)
```